# Removing white space and colon

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file with a bunch of numbers that have white spaces and colons and I am trying to remove them. As I have seen on this forum the function `line.strip.split()` works well to achieve this. Is there a way of removing the white space and colon all in one go? Using the method posted by Lorenzo I have this:

```
train = []
with open('C:/Users/Morgan Weiss/Desktop/STA5635/DataSets/dexter/dexter_train.data') as train_data:
    train.append(train_data.read().replace(' ','').replace(':',''))
size_of_train = np.shape(train)
for i in range(size_of_train[0]):
    for j in range(size_of_train[1]):
        train[i][j] = int(train[i][j])
print(train)
```

Although I get this error:

```
File "C:/Users/Morgan Weiss/Desktop/STA5635/Homework/Homework_1/HW1_Dexter.py", line 11, in <module>
    for j in range(size_of_train[1]):
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Well... you are not using valid python syntax! Grab some python tutorial and learn the loop-syntax. And **after** you did this, look at list-comprehensions.

Comment: This is not valid syntax! Look into list comprehension.

Comment: ok, I will do that thank you should I delete this question?

Comment: I'm not sure about deleting. But do your research and see if it helps. If not, edit your question with added information. If resolved, you should delete it, if there is no answer (maybe).

Comment: @sascha Ok, I read this: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk. But this does not seem to help any recommendations?

Comment: @Wolfy Seriously? You don't know anything about the programming language and think 2 minutes of reading some language-construct helps? Learn python from the beginning or all of your future work is doomed. A hint about your problem (if you use this to solve your problem without learning python, ... well...): did you ever see a **list-comprehension** which is not **within** ```[``` and ```]``` brackets?

Comment: @sascha I edited my question if you want to take a look maybe this is what you were talking about

Comment: @AndrewL. edited my post, is there a way of just deleting the colon and white space all in one line?

Comment: You can try one statement at a time with the built-in interpreter - start it at command prompt with `python` or `python3`. Build this complicated block up one bit at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the above syntax is not correct, but anyways as per your question, you can use replace function present in python.

When reading each line as a string from that file you can do something like,

```
train = []
with open('/Users/sushant.moon/Downloads/dexter_train.data') as f:
    list = f.read().split()
    for x in list:
        data = x.split(':')
        train.append([int(data[0]),int(data[1])])

# this part becomes redundant as i have already converted str to int before i append data to train
size_of_train = np.shape(train) 
for i in range(size_of_train[0]): 
    for j in range(size_of_train[1]): 
        train[i][j] = int(train[i][j])
```

Here I am using replace function to replace space with blank string, and similar with colon.

Comment: I tried your method but I get this error:   train.append(train_data.replace(' ','').replace(':',''))

AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: I tried it please see my edited post. Perhaps my syntax is incorrect? If you would be so kind as to see what I need to do to fix it

Comment: it seems train is 1 dimensional numpy array, please try printing train before you do np.shape(train) to check if everything is according to what you require.

Comment: Yes Train will be a 1 dimension, as we are just appending single lines to it.
Please upvote if the problem has solved

Comment: Yes that worked but why is my tuple index out of range for j does not make sense to me

Comment: How were you expecting the data to be, can you explain bit more about it.
Right now, we read the train_data, complete line as a string (single string) and we are performing replace operations on it, and then we append it to a list. Hence Train is a 1 dimension list instead of list of tuples, if you need tuples based on some character, suppose colon ,that can be done by just replacing replace(':','') with split(':')

Comment: I can send you the data file if you like? what is your email?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122788/discussion-between-lorenzo-and-wolfy).

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide an example of what your input file looks like so we can only speculate what solution you need. I'm going to suppose that you need to extract integers from your input text file and print their values.

Here's how I would do it:

- Instead of trying to eliminate whitespace characters and colons, I will be searching for digits using a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
- Consecutive digits would constitute a number
- I would convert this number to an integer form.

And here's how it would look like:

```
import re

input_filename = "/home/evens/Temporaire/Stack Exchange/StackOverflow/Input_file-39359816.txt"

matcher = re.compile(r"\d+")

with open(input_filename) as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        for digits_found in matcher.finditer(line):
            number_in_string_form = digits_found.group()
            number = int(number_in_string_form)
            print(number)
```

But before you run away with this code, you should continue to learn Python because you don't seem to grasp its basic elements yet.

Comment: You could start with the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/index.html) for example.

Comment: ok, is that necessary I used Matlab first and then went over to C++. I thought python was suppose to be rather easy

Comment: I can send you my code and assignment I have done the assignment successfully on a different data set but this one is giving me problems. I will compensate you for the time?

Comment: It is easy but it's different from Matlab or C++. (If it wasn't why bother ?) You still have to put minimal efforts to learn it. If you don't, you'll never be able to use it to its full potential. Trust us, this is not wasted time.

Comment: I don't have time to work for you and, in the long run, it would be best if you take the time to learn this stuff yourself.

Comment: I understand, I am doing some tutorials on Youtube. I am no longer using Spyder and I am using Sublime Text and the command prompt to run my code. Do you recommend something else?

Comment: I take that back I will use notepad++ unless you recommend something else